# Symfony 3 [Semantical Error] on authentication

Tags: symfony

After some hours of search I can't find what I'm doing wrong, here my case:

user entity:

```
/**
 * Many users belongs to one group
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Group", inversedBy="users")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_group", referencedColumnName="id")
 *
 */
private $group;
```

group entity:

```
/**
 * One group has many users
 * 
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="group")
 */
private $users;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->users = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

When a visitor sign-up this is the method in the controller:

```
/**
 *
 * @Route("/signup", name="signup")
 *
 */
public function signupAction(Request $request)
{

    $data = $request->request->all();
    $user = new User();
    $form = $this->createForm(SignupType::class, $user);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        // Create account
        $account = new Account();
        $account->getCreatedby($user);
        $account->setCreateddate(new \DateTime("now"));
        $account->setName($form['username']->getData());
        $account->setIsActive(true);

        $user->setAccount($account);    // relate this account to the user
        $user->setCreateddate(new \DateTime("now"));
        $user->setLocale('en'); // Assign the locale

        // Encoding the password
        $password = $this->get('security.password_encoder')
            ->encodePassword($user, $form['password']->getData());
        $user->setPassword($password);

        // Assign the group / role
        $group = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Group')->findOneBy( array('name' => strtolower($form['user_type']->getData())) );
        //exit(\Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($group));
        $user->addGroup($group);

        // Persist objects to database
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($account);
        $em->persist($user);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->render('default/show_message.html.twig', array(
            'alert_type' => 'success',
            'message' => 'You are registered',
            'redirect' => '',
        ));
    }

    return $this->render('security/signupForm.html.twig', array(
        'data' => $data,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));

}
```

This works nearly perfectly. The database is updated. But I noticed that in the field of user->group there is a null. When I uncomment the dump I see the right group data.

So when the visitor tries to log-in I get this log:

```
[2017-04-11 20:04:41] request.INFO: Matched route "login". {"route":"login","route_parameters":{"_controller":"AppBundle\\Controller\\SecurityController::loginAction","_route":"login"},"request_uri":"http://test.com/app_dev.php/login","method":"POST"} []
[2017-04-11 20:04:41] security.INFO: Authentication request failed. {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Exception\\AuthenticationServiceException(code: 0): [Semantical Error] line 0, col 60 near 'g WHERE u.username': Error: Class AppBundle\\Entity\\User has no association named groups at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\test_com\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Authentication\\Provider\\DaoAuthenticationProvider.php:94, Doctrine\\ORM\\Query\\QueryException(code: 0): [Semantical Error] line 0, col 60 near 'g WHERE u.username': Error: Class AppBundle\\Entity\\User has no association named groups at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\test_com\\vendor\\doctrine\\orm\\lib\\Doctrine\\ORM\\Query\\QueryException.php:63, Doctrine\\ORM\\Query\\QueryException(code: 0): SELECT u, g FROM AppBundle\\Entity\\User u LEFT JOIN u.groups g WHERE u.username = :username OR u.email = :email at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\test_com\\vendor\\doctrine\\orm\\lib\\Doctrine\\ORM\\Query\\QueryException.php:41)"} []
[2017-04-11 20:04:41] security.DEBUG: Authentication failure, redirect triggered. {"failure_path":"login_failure"} []
```

So I'm sure I have a problem with the group field but unable to find out.

Somebody to help me?. Thanks.

Comment: First, it seems you have a typo : ` $account->getCreatedby($user);`
I think it's ` $account->SetCreatedby($user);`

Comment: Thanks scoolnico. Yes, sorry about that. Corrected and still doing the same.

Comment: Did you try to check if your schema is valid? `bin/console doctrine:schema:validate` ?

Comment: The problem surely lies in your `$group = ...` line. Have you verified the `$form['user_type']` is returning what you expect? You should also add some error checking to prevent/detect this kind of problem, like before your `$group = ...` line, add `if (!$group) then { throw new Exception() } ` (or similar).

Comment: Thanks ehymel, the schema is valid, as I said in the question the tables are updated but I have a problem with the group.Thanks ehymel. As I said in the question when I uncomment the exit line the dump return the right group entity, in other words the right data of the selected group.

Answer (score 0):

In your `User` entity class, change

```
/**
 * Many users belongs to one group
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Group", inversedBy="users")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_group", referencedColumnName="id")
 *
 */
private $group;
```

to

```
/**
 * Many users belongs to one group
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Group", inversedBy="users", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_group", referencedColumnName="id")
 *
 */
private $group;
```

Comment: Thanks tftd, but when I make your change I get this on generating entities:
 
 [Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException]
 [Creation Error] The annotation @ORM\JoinColumn declared on property AppBun
 dle\Entity\User::$group does not have a property named "cascade". Available
  properties: name, referencedColumnName, unique, nullable, onDelete, column
 Definition, fieldName

Comment: @Carlos I'm sorry, I made a typo. The `cascade` part should be in your `@ORM\ManyToOne`. Please check the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks to everybody but nothing worked. Only when I convert the association into a ManyToMay it starts to work. The same with the relation with Account and User. I'm totaly confused.